# making a manual key for a graph of multiple data frames (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph made up of multiple data frames, and have been trying to create a key for it such that I can show the shape and color of the point with a designated label. This is the code:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_segment(df_pow, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xv, yend=yv), arrow=arrow(angle=5), size=.25, color="red") + 
  geom_point(data=df_pow, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y), size=2, shape=1, color="red") + 
  geom_segment(df_pCOR_ow, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xv, yend=yv), arrow=arrow(angle=5), size=.25, color="pink") + 
  geom_point(data=df_pCOR_ow, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y), size=2, shape=1, color="pink") +
  geom_segment(df_pCOR_uw, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xv, yend=yv), arrow=arrow(angle=5), size=.25, color="yellow") + 
  geom_point(data=df_pCOR_uw, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y), size=2, shape=5, color="yellow") +
  geom_segment(df_puw, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xv, yend=yv), arrow=arrow(angle=5), size=.25, color="orange") + 
  geom_point(data=df_puw, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y), size=2, shape=5, color="orange") +
  geom_segment(df_pay, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xv, yend=yv), arrow=arrow(angle=5), size=.25, color="green") + 
  geom_point(data=df_pay, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y), size=2, shape=2, color="green") +
  geom_segment(df_pay_, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xv, yend=yv), arrow=arrow(angle=5), size=.25, color="blue") + 
  geom_point(data=df_pay_, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y), size=2, shape=2, color="blue") +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  ggtitle("AMO2 Personal Story") +
  xlab("F2(HZ)") +
  ylab('F1(Hz)') + 
  xlim(2500, 500) + 
  ylim(800, 200)
```

my goal is a key showing [(name: ow, color: red, shape:1), (name: (COR)ow, color: pink, shape: 1), (name: (COR)uw, color: yellow, shape: 5), (name: uw, color: orange, shape: 5), (name: ay, color: green, shape: 2), (name: ay(-voice), color: blue: shape: 2)]. I have tried to use `scale_color_manual()`, however I do not think that I am doing so correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: merge the data into 1 data.frame - it will make ggplot much easier to use

Comment: Before trying to solve this specific problem, I'd recommend you take a step back and go through some `ggplot2` tutorials. [Here's one](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html) by the package author. `ggplot2`'s paradigm is based on assigning variables to aesthetics such as color, share, position, etc. If you're putting together a plot the way the package is intended to work, you usually *don't* need to be making repeated calls to the same `geom_*` to do similar things